# While installing goland ide on ubuntu 18.04 getting this ERROR: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing

Tags: installation, ubuntu-18.04, ide

While installing Goland IDE on Ubuntu 18.04 getting this error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /absolute/path/to/jetbrains-agent.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Download and extract the archive from the official website https://www.jetbrains.com/go/download/ and make sure it's fully downloaded/extracted before running it.